# which layer doest contain query for reading?

Tags: c#, architecture

My project has 4 layers: Presentation, application, domain, infrastructure.
I am using ORM for the write side. Read side, sometimes I have cases that have a complex query. I process by using a native query.

I write it at the infrastructure layer. But, I see some projects such as "ESHOPONWEB" write a native query in application layers.

Which layer should contain the native query?

Comment: in N-tier application architecture, it's done in the Data Access Layer

Comment: I think the infrastructure layer is the appropriate one

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "native query"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't familiar with ESHOPONWEB aka [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb), a reference architecture & implementation that Microsoft put out, but I see it has an accompanying [eBook](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/e-book/aspnet/pdf) which includes an "Architectural principles" section, another on "Common web application architectures", and at a glance other sections explain the architecture in more detail.

Using the book and code should give you a good way to learn the relevant concepts at your own pace.

> Which layer should contain the native query?

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "native query".   I did a quick search through the eBook and didn't see any obvious references to that.

Typical best practice architecture (like what is in the eBook) says that queries in the Application / Business Logic layer should be agnostic - meaning they should not contain any code or dependencies that tightly-couples the Business Logic to a specific Data Access provider.

So, if you need to query a data base, the **database specific** query code (or reference to a Stored Procedure in the database or any other database specific concept) should be in the Data Access code, which is in the Data Access (Infrastructure) layer.

If something in your Business Logic layer wants to do a query, there's three approaches that come to mind:

1. It wants to query itself, which it is free to do, using agnostic code against objects it already has.
2. It wants to query data from the database, it gets the Data Access to do that.  The query inputs and results need to be transported between these layers agnostically.  E.g. query results might come back as a collection/array/list of Data Transfer Objects (DTO) or Plain Old CLR/Class Objects (POCO).
3. You take some section of data from your database / Data Access layer, pre-load that as a database agnostic data model in the Business Logic layer, which it can query just like #1.

I'm not sure, but your Domain layer **might** be what you can use to do #3?

Does that make sense, and answer your question?

**Regarding Layers**

As the eShopOnWeb book explains, you want to keep various "concerns" (like business logic, UI, and data access all separate.  The separation is to make maintenance and change easier to manage, especially over a long time.  E.g.:

- Keeping the business logic layer/code separate from the UI layer/code means that you should be able to add new types of UI without having to re-write the application code.
- Keeping the business logic layer/code separate from data access layer/code means that you should be able to add/swap data providers (e.g. different types of database), and the business logic should be less impacted by database changes.

In the two points, above I say "should" because it depends on how clean and effective your separation is.

To translate that to your layers, UI is obviously your Presenation layer, Business Logic sounds like your Application and Domain layers, Data Access is your Infrastructure layer.

In the eBook they give an example (fig 5-1, pg 16) where they logically have those four layers you use but in the one code-base / package (it will all get deployed together).